# How to find child items of a collapsed tree item using C++ UI Automation?

Tags: c++, ui-automation

1. Is there a way to find child items of a collapsed tree item without expending it?
   It is easy task using winapi, but I can not see the child items in any view including content view, control view and raw view from Inspect.exe.
2. I don't know if I could cache the child items, because I observed that child items disappears once parent item get collapsed.

I don't know why the UI Automation API was designed like that, it isn't convenient at all.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee671657(v=vs.85).aspx

> Collapsed tree items do not appear in the control view or content view
>   until they become expanded and visible (or can be scrolled into view).

Any ideas?

Comment: Inspect MSAA with raw view is 'Not Responding' on the other hand, don't know why.

Comment: Tried MSAA with 'Visible Windows Only View', but seems the SysTreeView don't show hierarchy - all items including root items and their children are under the tree node directly.

Comment: "The ChildCount property for the tree view object is the number of items contained in the tree view. The ChildCount property for each tree view item is zero." - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd373668(v=vs.85).aspx